# Using pneumatic paint sprayer for wall texturing

Tags: drywall

I'm looking for a decent tutorial to get good results texturing dry wall (orange peel) using a sprayer.

Comment: Practice is the best way, there are some tutorials on U tube. Never use "hot mud" it can set up quickly and ruin your gun.

Comment: I just noticed you have paint sprayer in the title. I thought you were using a mud gun type sprayer. I would not put mud through a paint gun. Paint sprayers are designed to lay down an even coat if it has a compressor I doubt it will last long with mud. If it is a buzzer like an inexpensive Wagner I am sure it won't work at all due to the needed viscosity to create the Orange peel.